# Way to allow instantiating derived classes

Tags: 7

I have a class called MyService, a function to get the only instance of it custom_get_my_service(), and multiple functions a,b, etc that call the instance getter, as you can see below.

All of this is packaged into my module. Suppose I give this module to another developer, he can't change the code, but he needs to override some of my class methods, and all the custom_a, custom_b functions have to use his derived class.

How can I modify my custom_get_my_service() function, in a Drupal best practice way, to allow others to instantiate their derived class instead of my own?

```
class MyService {}

function custom_get_my_service() {
  $service = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, NULL);
  if (is_null($service)) {
    $service = new MyService();
  }
  return $service;
}

function custom_a() {
  $service = custom_get_my_service();
  // Do stuff
}

function custom_b() {
  $service = custom_get_my_service();
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it however you like, really; however PHP will let you.

Basically you need to make a decision at some point in `custom_get_my_service()` about which class you're going to use. Drupal's paradigm is hooks, so a contrived example might be:

```
function custom_get_my_service() {
  $service = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, NULL);
  if (is_null($service)) {
    $service_class = custom_get_service_class();
    $service = new $service_class();
  }
  return $service;
}

function custom_get_service_class() {
  // Default
  $class = 'MyService';

  $modules = module_implements('custom_service_class');
  foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $function = "{$module}_custom_service_class";
    $class = $function();
  }

  return $class;
}
```

Then another module would implement the hook:

```
function another_module_custom_service_class() {
  return 'AnotherClass';
}
```

Obviously that's a very limited example, which will only let one module override the class, has race conditions, no error checking, etc. But that's the basic idea, I'm sure you can extrapolate from there based on what your module is providing.

You could also look at a DI approach, and have modules pass in their implementations of an interface you define into your functions, which then make the necessary use of them. It kind of depends on your level of experience with OO, and your opinions on 'best practice'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe module_invoke_all would be better than just module_implements, because it allows others to implement hook_module_implements_alter(), to set ordering.

Rather than my opinion of best practice, I was expecting there to be some standard way to do it. I believe Views Handlers need to support the same derived class support, and maybe Entity API module.

I would be interested in seeing a DI approach used in D7, not D8 where it is already standard.

Comment: Not really - you're already calling `module_implements`, which invokes the alter hook anyway. Core does it this way (which is why I mentioned it as you were looking for Drupal best practice). I'm not sure what you mean about views handlers, they wouldn't come into this unless you're integrating with the views module, which is obviously an entirely different question. Same thing for the Entity API module - not relevant to what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I mean that Views provides default handlers (classes) for fields (example body). By implementing a certain hook, you can switch another class to be instantiated for that field. I believe it is the same use-case as the one I've described. Also Entity API provides a default controller class for nodes, you could probably switch it to use another custom derived one.

Comment: Sure, I didn't mention that because it would be massive overkill for your use case. If your module has the capacity to register _multiple_ service classes, then yes, always use the hook system to get those registered, even by your own module. Then provide an alter hook so classes can be changed, and consult the hooks every time you need to make a decision about which class to use. Seems like you already know about these methods, why the question? :)

Comment: Mostly to find out if there is a standard or better approach than what I've found in certain contributed modules.

Comment: That makes sense. There are other ways too, for example the way [`drupal_mail_system()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail_system/7) uses a _variable_ to store the class name, so it can over-written in settings.php, etc. In fact, that might be the more appropriate approach for your current use case, if you just have single purpose for the single class

Comment: I will evaluate both options. Thanks for your input!